# Many OR statements in tclsh

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I am trying to execute in tclsh the following code :

```
set t 2
if { $t > 0 || $t < 30 || $t < 20 } { puts yes }
```

In a tclsh shell, I get the following error :

```
syntax error in expression " $t > 0 || $t < 30 || $t < 20 ": character not legal in expressions
```

What is the character that is not legal here ? I suspected '<' to be the problem but then I ran this command :

```
if { $t > 0 } { puts yes }
```

and I got 'yes' printed as expected.

Comment: Note that your logic is valid for all values of `t` since -1 is less than 30 and 1000000 is more than 0. Be very careful about the formal meaning of OR and AND (it's actually the same as linguistic meaning but as humans we often use language carelessly and use OR and AND wrongly though others seem to magically understand what we mean even if we are not logically correct)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid, I would check the settings of your editor.

Answer (score 0):

All visible characters appear legal. It's probably some sort of invisible space or something like that; Tcl 8.4 basically only really handled ASCII correctly in expressions (outside of quoted constants).